# Int32.Parse("356882") generate exception System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to parse a string in c# but I am getting a format exception, the code I am using is :

```
int test;
test =Int32.Parse("﻿356882");
```

I don't get why this generates an error, 356882 is an integer within the boundaries of an int32.

Any idea?

Cheers

Vincent

Comment: You have a hidden character in the string before 3. delete the string and type again. test =Int32.Parse("356882");

Comment: Additionally, you can "clean" string to keep only numbers `Regex.Replace("356882", "[^0-9]", "")`, or use `Int32.TryParse("356882", out test);` which will not raise an error on wrong strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 356882 is an integer

Yes, it would be an integer. "356882" is an integer.

But this is not what you are parsing. Yor string is:

"﻿356882"

There is a hidden fist character. I copy pasted it from your text - my right key hangs one press. That hidden character is blocking parsing.

Now sure how it ends up there - copy/paste and what editor?

Comment: Whaou thanks a lot, I copied it from an Odata response ( count number of entities). SO mus be why it's blocking.